# How to bypass GAC for strong name assemblies?

Tags: .net

I have a debug version of an assembly which has a strong name. I want to install the assembly in the bin folder of a web application.

However, the CLR checks if a strong named assembly exists in a GAC before continuing with the rest of the probing. For my web application, I want the CLR to bypass looking into the GAC. Rather, I want the CLR to look into my bin folder first, and if it is not available look at the GAC. How can I do this?

Comment: You cannot override the fundamental way the CLR looks for assemblies, GAC is always first.  Change the [AssemblyVersion] or uninstall it from the GAC.  The latter should never be a problem on a web server.

Comment: GAC is not always first. See http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/12215/Assemblies-locating-binding-and-deploying

Comment: Addition: What the article does not tell is that you can add the developmentMode-Tag not just to the machine.config but to the app.config as well. Defining an environment variable "DEVPATH" that includes the folders the CLR should look for the assembly, works for me to bypass the GAC (both assemblies have the same strong name).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hans is correct.

DON'T do this - but just for interests sake;

---EXCOMMUNICATION EXCLUSION ZONE---

I do believe from experience that if you install another copy of an assembly (ie your debug version, with same version number), that there will be 2 copies in the GAC and the latest one installed will be used.

---END EXCOMMUNICATION EXCLUSION ZONE---

As Hans says, give your debug version a new version number and point to it with a publisher policy (which you put in the gac too), or an assembly redirect.